# Is it possible to specify who is allowed to set a ClearCase attribute on a file?

Tags: version-control, clearcase, configuration-management

Just what the title says: can I control what user is able to modify ClearCase attributes
on a file-per-file basis based on some kind of permission system?

I am using Unix, but it also might be interesting to know if this is possible
on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default permission system is the one described with the cleartool command for modifying an attribute *value*: [`cleartool mkattr`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkattr.htm) (which is not the same as creating a new attribute *type*:  [`cleartool mkattype`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkattype.htm))

> ### ACL authorization
>
> If ACLs are enabled, the principal must have the following permissions:
>
> - To attach an attribute to a policy, rolemap, or VOB: read-info on object, mod-attr on object, read-info on VOB object
> - To attach an attribute to a version or element: mod-attr on element, read-info on element, read-info on VOB object
> - Other operations: read-info on VOB object, one of the non-ACL authorization identities
>
> ### Non-ACL authorization
>
> You must have one of the following identities:
>
> - Element owner
> - Element group member
> - Object owner
> - Object group member
> - VOB owner
> - root (UNIX and Linux)
> - Member of the ClearCase administrators group ( ClearCase on Windows)

That applies on Linux or Windows, but depends on your ClearCase version.
Starting with ClearCase 8.0.1, you can activate ACLs: see "[ACL enforcement and enablement for VOBs and VOB objects](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/c_acl_enable_enfrc.htm)".

In your case, enabling ACLs would be closer to what you are looking from: [policies, and rolemaps](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/effective-governance-compliance-clear-case-ACLs/index.html)

> ### Policies
>
> Policies have four sections:
>
> - VOB,
> - policy,
> - rolemap, and
> - element.
>
> Each section specifies an access control list, or ACL, which is a list of ACEs.
>   Each ACE identifies a principal and the permissions granted to that principal.
>   Policies typically specify Role principals, thereby defining role names used in the policy. Policies can also list specific users or groups.
>
> ### Rolemaps
>
> Rolemaps assign specific users or groups to the roles defined in the associated policy.

Answer (score 1):

If VOB ACLs are not enabled, you can do this with a trigger as well. You can create an element trigger and only attach it to.the desired elements. "mkattr" is one of the operations you can set a trigger on.

Personally, I would use a preop trigger pointing to a simple script containing "exit 0;" and set access on the SCRIPT so that only the desired users can execute it. Any failure to access/execute a preop trigger is treated as a failure and blocks the operation. This is faster than an "nusers" list if the "allowed users" list on a "block users" trigger gets too large.